# Randomly pick two numbers in a range so that the sum of their squares is constant

Tags: c#, math, random, pythagorean

I'm currently developing a 2-player Ping-Pong game (in 2D - real simple) from scratch, and it's going good. However Theres a problem I just can't seem to solve - I'm not sure if this should be located here or on MathExchange - anyway here goes.

Initially the ball should be located in the center of the canvas. When pressing a button the ball should be fired off in a completely random direction - but always with the same velocity.

The Ball object has (simplified)  4 fields - The position in X and Y, and the velocity in X and Y.  This makes it simple to bounce the ball off the walls when it hits, simple by inverting the velocities.

> ```
>     public void Move()
>     {
>         if (X - Radius < 0 || X + Radius > GameWidth)
>         {
>             XVelocity = -XVelocity;
>         }
>         if (Y - Radius < 0 || Y + Radius > GameHeight)
>         {
>             YVelocity = -YVelocity;
>         }
>         X+= XVelocity;
>         Y+= YVelocity;
>     }
> ```

I figured the velocity should be the same in each game, so I figures I would use Pythagoras - the square of the two velocities should always be the same.

SO for the question:

Is there a way to randomly select two numbers (doubles) such that the sum of their squares is always a specific number - more formally:

> ```
> double x = RandomDouble();
> double y = RandomDouble();
> if (x^2 + y^2 = 16) {/* should always be true */ }
> ```

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Randomly pick an angle `theta` and multiply that by the magnitude of the distance `d` you want.  Something like:

```
double theta = rand.NextDouble() * 2.0 * Math.PI;
double x = d * Math.Cos(theta);
double y = d * Math.Sin(theta);
```

Comment: +1 Definitely the simple and right way if you want the angle to be uniformly distributed

Comment: Exactly. This problem is equivalent to picking a point on the surface of a sphere.

Comment: Works like a charm - a much better solution than what I thought of :)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Not quite the same as the problem with a sphere.  Using this approach with a sphere will lead to clustering at the poles.  See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html

Comment: @AndersNK Glad this was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If the constant is `C`, pick a number `x` between `0` and `sqrt(C)`.

Solve for the other number `y` using simple algebra.

Answer (score 0):

why not try this:

```
double x = RandomDouble();
double y = square(16-x^2);
```

as your application allow double type.
does this solve your problem?
if not, please let me know